# Wrong result for URL extraction in Swift

Tags: swift, ios10

With Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002), why do I get `let result = "4247577657"` here? I am trying to figure out how my code pulled this from my url variable.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.allowsCellularAccess = true

let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

let url = NSURL(string: "http://kvisionphoto.com/4247577657.txt")

let task = session.dataTask(with: url as! URL) {
    (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else {print (error ?? "error") ; return}

    let result =  try? String(contentsOf: url as! URL)

    print(result ?? "nil" )

    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: Please read how to ask a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why are you using `String(contentsOf:)` inside the completion block of a `URLSession`? You already have the data inside the completion block.

Comment: @rmaddy That's pretty much my question. I got exactly what I was looking for: "4247577657" with that code and it makes zero sense to me.

Comment: @Pierce I did and I guess I didn't get it. Sorry I'm a beginner, but I promise to do better next time.

Answer (score 1):

4247577657 is the text on the server...

[image: Here's what I get]

Comment: Thanks, but I need a bit more. The url value is the complete web address I am using  but when I cast it to the URL type it turns into "4247577657". That is my question.

Comment: @gosborne3 - I think what he's telling you is that it returns a text file, and that's the text it contains.

Comment: @Pierce No wonder people were scratching their heads. Apologies on this one. The person that gave me the URL put the string in the text file and I didn't see it. Thanks very much.